# Re-organizing string input and calculating averages in basic python or numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have data looking like this:

```
met = """
       A     B   C    D    E     F
idx1   1     3   5    5    7     10
idx2   2     3   6    12   6     1
.... """"
```

What I want is this output, where X is the average of A and D, Y the average of B and E, and Z the average of C and F.

```
output = """
         X    Y    Z
idx1      3   5    7.5
idx2      7   4.5  3.5 """
```

Just thinking about how to approach this: I thought to basically to slice each line up in the two parts and then calculate averages on corresponding values in each part (index 1 with 1; 2 with 2, 3 with 3) and output that result.

I'd prefer to see if I can do this efficiently in basic pytho, but alternatively a solution involving numpy or pandas would be possibly too.

Thank you.

Comment: The reason you get that error is that you can't use a list as a key in a dictionary, because lists are mutable. The solution to that is to make a tuple with the same elements (because tuples are immutable, and therefore hashable if their elements are hashable): `d[tuple(idx)]` instead of `d[idx]`. But in this case, that doesn't make sense. You presumably want want to add all of the elements in `june` into the same dictionary entry (otherwise, you'd just do `d[idx] += june`). So… what _do_ you want?

Comment: As a side note, consider using `for row in csv.reader(mets, delimiter="\t"):` instead of parsing the file yourself.

Comment: Thanks. When I use `d[tuple(idx)]` I get this error : `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'add'`

Comment: Well, yes, that's another problem; lists don't have an `add` method, only sets do; lists have `append` (and a few other things, like `insert`). But, as I said, what you're trying to do here doesn't make sense anyway, so… who cares about getting it right?

Answer (score 1):

First, the reason for that error is that you're trying to use `idx`, a list, as a key in the dictionary, `d`. You can't use mutable values like lists as dictionary keys. (Otherwise, you could just mutate the list, and your dictionary would suddenly be invalid.) The usual solution is to create a tuple with the same elements as the list (because tuples are immutable, and therefore hashable if their elements are hashable), like `d[tuple(idx)]`.

But in this case, that wouldn't make any sense. Doing that would just add each `val` onto the same dictionary value. (Actually, it wouldn't even do that, because `list.add` doesn't exist. You probably wanted `list.append` here. But since, again, it doesn't make sense or do anything useful, it's not worth putting too much effort into figuring out how to do it right…) If you wanted that, you could just skip the loop and do `d[tuple(idx)] += june`, but I can't imagine why you'd want that.

I think what you're trying to do is use the corresponding `idx` entry for each `june` entry. You could do that by `zip`ping the two lists together, but really, there's a much easier way: Just use them immediately as you generate them, instead of storing them and then trying to figure out how to use them later:

```
for line in mets:
    fields = line.split("\t")
    idx = fields[0]
    june = fields[1:4]
    july = fields[4::]
    d[idx] += june
```

However, even this doesn't really make sense. Assuming you're going to do the same thing for `july` you did with `june`, this is just going to just add `fields[1:]` back together.

From your `intermediate`, it looks like what you actually want is to use the `idx` and the june-vs.-july-ness together as a key. Which is easy:

```
d = {}
for line in mets:
    fields = line.split("\t")
    idx = fields[0]
    june = fields[1:4]
    july = fields[4::]
    d[idx, 'a'] = june
    d[idx, 'b'] = july
```

Or maybe you don't even want a dict at all, just a list:

```
d = []
for line in mets:
    fields = line.split("\t")
    idx = fields[0]
    june = fields[1:4]
    july = fields[4::]
    d.append([idx, 'a'] + june)
    d.append([idx, 'b'] + july)
```

Comment: Can I ask, I suppose the problem is clear (is it?) in that case, how would you approach this/what seems like the best approach? using numpy?

Comment: @oaklander114: The problem really isn't clear to me. Do you need to be able to construct that `intermediate`, or do you only need `output`? Do you need to construct that final string, or some data structure that you can use in some way? Given that you were using a dict, is the order actually unimportant?